# Make Amazon Forecast trigger a Lambda function when done performing task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-forecast

Some tasks within Amazon Forecast can take a long time, and I would like it to trigger a Lambda function once it finishes a long task (creating import jobs, training models, making forecasts, etc...) so this Lambda function can update my database, for example.

How can I do it? Can I use something like Amazon SNS or SQS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Forecast has onboarded on to Amazon EventBridge or Amazon CloudWatch Events.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/notifications.html